# How to write a function to edit raw input in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, edit

I'm writing a program that takes the user input and saves it in an array. I'm currently trying to write a function that edits the data in the array. So far I have:

```
data = []
user_input = int(raw_input('How many Subject do you wish to add? : '))
for i in range (0, user_input):
    x = raw_input('Enter Subject: ')
    data.append(x)

print(data)
```

Comment: What have you done so far in the function you are trying to write? Also, what do you want to edit?

Comment: It looks like you have successfully stored the data into an array. In what way are you trying to edit the data?

Comment: Why can't I edit this question to make the code readable? The edit button is grey.

Comment: Yep, so once the array has been filled with items. The next function in my code asks the user if they would like to edit any of the items saved in the array. So far I have coded this:

yes = 1
no = 2
print "would you like to add/remove any items in list"
print "1: yes"
print "2: no"
edit_input = int(raw_input('choose?: '))
if edit_input == 1:
    print(data)

Comment: @W0rmSp17 Please paste your whole code..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
data = []
user_input = int(raw_input('How many Subject do you wish to add? : ')) 

for i in range (0, user_input): 
    x = raw_input('Enter Subject: ') 
    data.append(x) 

while True:
    print ("would you like to add/remove any items in list")
    print ("1: yes")
    print ("2: remove")
    print ("3: exit")
    edit_input = int(raw_input('choose?: '))
    if edit_input == 1:
        edit_data = raw_input('Enter a new Subject: ')
        data.append(edit_data)
    elif edit_input == 2:
        edit_data = raw_input('Enter a Subject you want to remove: ')
        if edit_data in data:
            data.remove(edit_data)
        else:
            print('Subject not found!')
    else:
        # breaking off the loop here
        break

print data
```

Comment: @DineshPanchananam Did you actually try to run this code? `if user_input == ""` is **always** going to be `False`, since a variable of type `int` can **never** be an empty string (so it gives a `ValueError` if the user just presses Enter on the first prompt or enters something like `two`). If you want to check the user input, use a `try ... except` construction.

Answer (score -2):

From what I understood I have this code for you.

```
data = []
user_input = int(raw_input('How many Subject do you wish to add? : '))
for i in range (0, user_input):
    x = raw_input('Enter Subject: ')
    data.append(x)

print(data)
yes = 1
no = 2
print "would you like to add/remove any items in list"
print "1: yes"
print "2: no"
edit_input = int(raw_input('choose?: '))
if edit_input == 1:
    edit_data = raw_input('Enter few more Subjects: ')
    data.append(edit_data)
else:
    edit_data = raw_input('Enter Subjects you want to remove: ')
    if edit_data in data:
        data.remove(edit_data)
    else:
        print "element not found"
print data
```

Comment: What happens when the user doesn't understand it needs to enter an int and enters `"two"`? Or just presses enter?

Comment: @Neftas Those conditions can be taken care of. You could use `dict` two map the numbers with it's words. `try` and `except` or simple `if/elif` conditions would come to rescue too. I hate writing the smart code for free :P so I just made necessary changes to get what OP asked for.